# How can i put plots beneath each other and side by side using markdown and html output?

Tags: r, plot, alignment, markdown, dygraphs

I have three groups of diagrams, and every group contains three diagrams. So what I want is, that the diagrams of one group are one below the other, and next to them are the other groups of diagrams.

I'm doing this on markdown using a html output.

My plots are already grouped in three groups, and are called a,b,c...,
but when I run the code, all 9 diagrams are below each other and not like
a d g
b e h
c f i

My code looks like this:

For the plots and different groups:

```
a <- dygraph(delta, main = "delta P I.Test feed", height=400,

        group = "Petronell") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector()
```

And for the markdown:

````
<style type="text/css">
  .main-container {
    max-width: 1800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  h1.title {
      font-size: 38px;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>

```{r global_options, message=FALSE, warning=TRUE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=3, fig.height=3, echo = F, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

```{r plot, fig.align="left"}
source("N:/H811/FlowRes/Pilotanlage_Petronell/R/dygraph/dygraph.R")
a
b
c
```

```{r,fig.align="center"}
source("N:/H811/FlowRes/Pilotanlage_Petronell/R/dygraph/dygraph.R")
b
d
e
```

```{r,fig.align="right"}
source("N:/H811/FlowRes/Pilotanlage_Petronell/R/dygraph/dygraph.R")
g
h
i
```
````

So my question is, **why is fig.align not changing anything**? Or how do I have to change the code?

Answer (score 0):

With an RMarkdown document, one code chunk is executed and converted to latex (or whatever you're converting to), then below, this is repeated for the next chunk.

Try putting all of your plots in the same chunk:

````
```{r}
source(abc)
source(def)
source(ghi)
```
````

If this fails, you may want to make your 3x3 set of plots by specifying the layout and then making each plot:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3)) #set the number and layout of plots

plot() #position [1,1]
...    #other 7 plots
plot() #position [3,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options

My code looks now loke this:

````
---
title: "Pilotanlage"
author: ""
date: ""
output: html_document
---

<style>

.main-container {
    max-width: 1800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

  }

h1.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;


}
</style>




```{r global_options, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=3, fig.height=3, echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

<div class="col-md-4">
```{r}
source("N:/H811/FlowRes/Pilotanlage_Petronell/R/dygraph/dygraph.R")
a
b
c
```
</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
```{r}
source("N:/H811/FlowRes/Pilotanlage_Petronell/R/dygraph/dygraph.R")
d 
e
f
```
</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
```{r}
source("R/dygraph/dygraph.R")
g 
h
j
```
</div>
````